# How can I write a LINQ query to discard the else portion of CASE statement SQL?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my SQL query:

`select distinct r.Sub as Subflows from 
(select case when TName like '%hig%' or TName like '%fas%' then 'High'
when TName like '%mid%' or TName like '%med%' then 'Medium' 
when TName like '%low%'  then 'Low' end as Subf FROM Sub)r where r.Subf is not null`

So I have a table called Sub and the distinct TNames are Low,Medium,Middle,Fast,High, 1,2,3,unknown in the table.

I want to display only those TNames which are Low,Medium,Middle,Fast and High.

I have got the right answer by given SQL query.

How can I write this in LINQ especially discarding the **else** part of **CASE** in SQL?

(When I use CASE syntax in LINQ, I have to use a ternary operator and as a result, at the last, I am forced to specify the else condition of CASE which I don't want to)
Also assume my LINQ classes and their fields are same as the columns and table names given here. (I can't paste the Entity framework classes here)

Comment: Use format : (a == b) ? true : false

Comment: I want to discard the 'false' part. it's like if-else if-else if. Thats it. There's no else.

Comment: The put null or empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you clearly, here is the linq version of the sql query you have specified in your question. It is an example of case-when usage in linq as well.

```
from s in Sub
let subf = ( s.TName.StartsWith("hig") || s.TName.StartsWith("fas") ? "High" :
             s.TName.StartsWith("mid") || s.TName.StartsWith("med") ? "Medium" :
             s.TName.StartsWith("low") ? "Low" :
            "Other")
group s by subf into g
select new { g.Key };
```

EDIT: To discard "Other" part, you need to use "where" clause. Not 100% sure about the syntax but it is probably:

```
from s in Sub
let subf = ( s.TName.StartsWith("hig") || s.TName.StartsWith("fas") ? "High" :
             s.TName.StartsWith("mid") || s.TName.StartsWith("med") ? "Medium" :
             s.TName.StartsWith("low") ? "Low" :
            "Other")
where subf !=  "Other"
group s by subf into g
select new { g.Key };
```

There is an example here you can benefit from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause

Comment: Is it possible to discard "Other" because this is the part I want to omit? Else this is correct.

Comment: if subf != "Other" does not work, please try !subf.equals("other")